# Is it obligatory to have a return/onward ticket while traveling between Schengen member states?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-of-onward-travel

Let's say I'm a non-EU national who has a Schengen visa type C for tourism. I want to visit multiple  Schengen member states. My first port of entry is Italy (for example) and I booked for two way round trip ticket for Italy (which means my last port of departure will be Italy as well).

So while traveling to Germany (for example) from Italy will they require me to have a return / onward ticket from Germany?

Comment: So you already have the visa and mean when traveling within the Schengen area? When flying, i.e. you will be controlled when boarding a flight from Italy to Germany? The answer is no, there will be no such checks, you can fly from Italy to any other Schengen country without a need for a return ticket. And the same holds for any other means of travel.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, yes, you're right, that's what I'm asking, and I'd appreciate if you add some references!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, +1 btw. I will not post an answer now and tbh it may be hard to come up with official sources, as it is now something as a matter of course thing. Think of Schengen as one country where the actual countries for entry reasons are like states in the U.S. While my citizenship is Schengen, I have travelled with non EU/Schengen friends within Schengen and they were never asked for this. Note that there is not even a visa control and at most airlines care about your visa being valid, not an onward ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking you don't even need a return ticket when traveling *to* the Schengen Area. The relevant regulation ([Schengen Border Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399), Article 6) only lists the following related requirement:

> (c) they justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and they
>   have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the
>   intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit
>   to a third country into which they are certain to be admitted, or are
>   in a position to acquire such means lawfully;

As for traveling between the Schengen members states - **no, it's not necessary to have an onward ticket of any kind**. You do need to have a valid visa and you can't exceed the 90/180 limit, but you won't pass border controls and you won't be asked for any sort of supporting documentation. Such checks are only done at the external border.

Comment: This is true, HOWEVER... `Annex I` is quite confusing int his, in fact:
 
for journeys undertaken for the purposes of tourism or for private reasons:
(iii) supporting documents as regards return: a return or round-trip ticket;

Comment: @Treviño yes, but that's for visa nationals, not for Annex II citizens